# ActiveShipping Ups Could not obtain shipping label. Missing or invalid shipper name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create ups shipping using [active_shpping](https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping) gem. I'm not sure if i'm doing everything properly but every time I try to create shipment i got `Runtime Error Could not obtain shipping label. Missing or invalid shipper name.`. In order to reproduce this problem:

```
packages = [
  ActiveMerchant::Shipping::Package.new( 100, [93,10]),
  ActiveMerchant::Shipping::Package.new( 100, [93,10])
]

origin = ActiveMerchant::Shipping::Location.new( :country => 'US', :state => 'CA', :city => 'Beverly Hills', :zip => '90210', :name => 'random name')

destination = ActiveMerchant::Shipping::Location.new( :country => 'CA', :province => 'ON', :city => 'Ottawa', :postal_code => 'K1P 1J1')
ups = ActiveMerchant::Shipping::UPS.new(:login => 'my-working-login', :password => 'my-working-password', :key => 'my-working-ups-key')

ups.create_shipment(origin, destination, packages)
```

Am I missing any parameter? Or perhaps creating shippment via UPS is unsupported?

Comment: were you ever able to figure this out?  I am having the same issue.